# How to clean up when a view is longer displayed?

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

I have a custom ImageView which starts a task to download an image from the web.
What I exactly want for the task is to continue running while app is on current activity, even if the view is not present (for example in a scrolling gridview) which is how it is right now, but I also want to cancel the task if the user left the activity.
Is there a particular method I can override for this? (something like onDestroy) or do I have to do it manually?

My custom view has a setImageUrl which starts the task for the url, other than that it's almost the same as ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you implemented your Task to downalod!but you can use IntentService or a local Service which binds to your Activity, so when your Activity finishes, your Task will no longer Active.